# Reutilizar una animación en varias barras de progreso

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una barra de progreso circular que está animada con CSS y JS que funciona perfectamente. Deseo poder reutilizar este código y crear varias barras de progreso.

El código JS funciona, ya que el número que muestra el porcentaje cambia, lo que no funciona es la animación CSS.

Para que la animación funcione para distintas barras, use clases con la intención de que estas clases modifiquen una variable global que limitaría el recorrido de la animación en CSS.

La animación si lee el valor de la animación, pero este valor nunca se modifica.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

```js
function graficar_porcentaje(div_porcentaje){
let numero_porcentaje = div_porcentaje.innerHTML.slice(0,div_porcentaje.innerHTML.length-1);
console.log(numero_porcentaje);
let counter=0;
setInterval(() => {
   if(counter==numero_porcentaje){
    clearInterval;
   }else{
    counter+=1;
    div_porcentaje.innerHTML=counter+"%" 
   }
}, 30);
}
```

```css
:root{
--per_skill:292.5;
}
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
background-color: #e3edf7;
height: 100hv;
display: flex;
align-items: center; /* Vertical Alignment*/
justify-content: center; /* Horizontal Alignment*/
}
.skills{
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
position: relative;
}
.outer{
height: 160px;
width: 160px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
            -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
border-radius: 50% ;
}
.inner{
height: 120px;
width: 120px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
            inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7),
            -0.5px -0.5px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1),
            0.5px 0.5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
            0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
border-radius: 50%;
}
#Java{
font-weight:600;
color: #555;
font-size: 30px;
}

#HTML{
font-weight:600;
color: #555;
font-size: 30px;
}

.percent-0::after{
--per_skill:450.0;
}

.percent-5::after{
--per_skill:427.5;
}

.percent-10::after{
--per_skill:405.0;
}

.percent-15::after{
--per_skill:382.5;
}

.percent-20::after{
--per_skill:360.0;
}

.percent-25::after{
--per_skill:337.5;
}

.percent-30::after{
--per_skill:315.0;
}

.percent-35::after{
--per_skill:292.5;
}

.percent-40::after{
--per_skill:270.0;
}

.percent-45::after{
--per_skill:247.5;
}

.percent-50::after{
--per_skill:225.0;
}

.percent-55::after{
--per_skill:202.5;
}

.percent-60::after{
--per_skill:180.0;
}

.percent-65::after{
--per_skill:157.5;
}

.percent-70::after{
--per_skill:135.0;
}

.percent-75::after{
--per_skill:112.5;
}

.percent-80::after{
--per_skill:90.0;
}

.percent-85::after{
--per_skill:67.5;
}

.percent-90::after{
--per_skill:45.0;
}

.percent-95::after{
--per_skill:22.5;
}

.percent-100::after{
--per_skill:0.0;
}


.una_skill{
position: relative;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;

}
.una_skill h3{
text-align: center;

}
svg{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

@keyframes anim {
100%{
    stroke-dashoffset:var(--per_skill);
}
}
circle{
fill: none;
stroke: url(#GradientColor);
stroke-width: 20px;
stroke-dasharray: 450;
stroke-dashoffset: 450;
animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="JS/app.js"></script>
<title>Circular Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="skills">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="skill">
            <div class="una_skill percent-65">
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div >65%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                            <stop offset-"0%" stop-color="#DA22FF" /> 
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9733EE" /> 
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
                </svg>
                <h3>Java</h3>
            </div>
            
           
        </li>

        <li class="skill">
            <div class="una_skill percent-35">
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div>35%</div>
                    </div>   
                </div>

                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                            <stop offset-"0%" stop-color="#DA22FF" /> 
                            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9733EE" /> 
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
                </svg>
                <h3>HTML</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
</div>

   


<script>
    let lista_porcentajes= document.getElementsByClassName('inner');
    for(let div_skill of lista_porcentajes){
        //graficar_porcentaje(document.getElementById("number"));
        graficar_porcentaje(div_skill.firstElementChild);
    }
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo el error están en las clases `.percent-` sin el `::after` funciona correctamente.

```js
let lista_porcentajes = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');
for (let div_skill of lista_porcentajes) {
  //graficar_porcentaje(document.getElementById("number"));
  graficar_porcentaje(div_skill.firstElementChild);
}


function graficar_porcentaje(div_porcentaje) {
  let numero_porcentaje = div_porcentaje.innerHTML.slice(0, div_porcentaje.innerHTML.length - 1);
  console.log(numero_porcentaje);
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    if (counter == numero_porcentaje) {
      clearInterval;
    } else {
      counter += 1;
      div_porcentaje.innerHTML = counter + "%"
    }
  }, 30);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --per_skill: 292.5;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e3edf7;
  height: 100hv;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Vertical Alignment*/
  justify-content: center;
  /* Horizontal Alignment*/
}

.skills {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.outer {
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), -0.5px -0.5px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.5px 0.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#Java {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#HTML {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.percent-0 {
  --per_skill: 450.0;
}

.percent-5 {
  --per_skill: 427.5;
}

.percent-10 {
  --per_skill: 405.0;
}

.percent-15 {
  --per_skill: 382.5;
}

.percent-20 {
  --per_skill: 360.0;
}

.percent-25 {
  --per_skill: 337.5;
}

.percent-30 {
  --per_skill: 315.0;
}

.percent-35 {
  --per_skill: 292.5;
}

.percent-40 {
  --per_skill: 270.0;
}

.percent-45 {
  --per_skill: 247.5;
}

.percent-50 {
  --per_skill: 225.0;
}

.percent-55 {
  --per_skill: 202.5;
}

.percent-60 {
  --per_skill: 180.0;
}

.percent-65 {
  --per_skill: 157.5;
}

.percent-70 {
  --per_skill: 135.0;
}

.percent-75 {
  --per_skill: 112.5;
}

.percent-80 {
  --per_skill: 90.0;
}

.percent-85 {
  --per_skill: 67.5;
}

.percent-90 {
  --per_skill: 45.0;
}

.percent-95 {
  --per_skill: 22.5;
}

.percent-100 {
  --per_skill: 0.0;
}

.una_skill {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.una_skill h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes anim {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--per_skill);
  }
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: url(#GradientColor);
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-dasharray: 450;
  stroke-dashoffset: 450;
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="JS/app.js"></script>
  <title>Circular Progress Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="skills">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li class="skill">
        <div class="una_skill percent-65">
          <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
              <div>65%</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                                <stop offset-"0%" stop-color="#DA22FF" /> 
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9733EE" /> 
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
                    </svg>
          <h3>Java</h3>
        </div>


      </li>

      <li class="skill">
        <div class="una_skill percent-35">
          <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
              <div>35%</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                                <stop offset-"0%" stop-color="#DA22FF" /> 
                                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9733EE" /> 
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
                    </svg>
          <h3>HTML</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Edward!!

Comment: @HernanFresco con mucho gusto, me alegro que te haya servido :)